# RegEx Query return nth match

Tags: regex, vba, ms-access

Basically, I have a regex expression in an Access query which pulls a *product code* from a long string of text. There is up to 10 codes in each string and I need ten fields in my query to pull each of the ten codes.

So far I can only get it to pull the first or last code by changing `Global = True|False`. The code I'm using is below:

```
Function extSKU( _
    Comments As Variant)

    Dim SKU_re As New RegExp
    SKU_re.Pattern = "\n\d{4,5}[A-Z]{0,1}"
    SKU_re.Global = False
    SKU_re.IgnoreCase = True
    Dim SKU_m
    For Each SKU_m In SKU_re.Execute(Comments)
      extSKU = Replace(Trim(UCase(SKU_m.Value)), "Completed By: ", "")
    Next
End Function
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: You are overwriting extSKU each time. Did you want to append this to a string, or add this to a collection? Appending to a stringwould look like `extSKU = extSKU  & Replace(Trim(UCase(SKU_m.Value)), "Completed By: ", "")` You should type your function return value, too.

Comment: Hi, That is spot on, creates a string which I could then divide into each of the ten fields but I thing a collection is probably the way forward. I've tried to declare a new collection and and Coll.Add SKU_m.Value in the for loop but it breaks my function and all the other regex in my query!

Comment: Hi, Fixed it. didn't declare as NEW collection. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Curious, how are you calling this function?

Comment: As an expression in an access query. Which pulls the pattern from a long text field which is the content of an email.

Answer (score 0):

Final answer: This pulls the first of ten SKUs and I have ten different functions for each of the SKU with an IF to return null if there aren't n matches.

```
Function extSKU1( _
  Comments As Variant)
  Dim SKU_re As New RegExp
  SKU_re.Pattern = "\n\d{4,5}[A-Z]{0,1}\s{0,1}(\d{0,3})"
  SKU_re.Global = True
  SKU_re.IgnoreCase = True
  Dim SKU_m
  Dim SKU As New Collection
  For Each SKU_m In SKU_re.Execute(Comments)
    SKU.Add Trim(UCase(SKU_m.Value))
  Next
  extSKU1 = SKU(1)
End Function
```